# Taking the homotopy fiber of $f : X \to Y$ twice gives the loop space $\Omega Y$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm attempting the following question,

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of pointed spaces. Show that the homotopy fiber of the map $\textrm{hofib}(f) \to X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega Y$. Conclude that there is a sequence
$$
\ldots \to \Omega \textrm{hofib}(f) \to \Omega X \to \Omega Y \to \textrm{hofib}(f) \to X \to Y, 
$$
where each map is obtained (up to homotopy equivalence) by taking the homotopy fiber of the next one in the sequence.

My attempt so far:

The homotopy fiber of $f$ is given by the following pullback

[image]

Since the right map is a Hurewicz fubration, the left map $\textrm{hofib}(f) \to X$ is also a Hurewicz fibration. Hence, we know that its homotopy fiber is weakly homotopy equivalent to its fiber.
We have that the fiber of $ev_1 : PY \to Y$ is given by $\Omega Y$. Denote $F$ for the fiber of $\textrm{hofib}(f) \to X$. Somehow I would like to compare these two fibers, but how? I was thinking about the l.e.s. of both fibrations, but that would only give a weak homotopy equivalence. Any ideas?

Comment: Try proving that the pullback of a fibration has the same fiber as the original fibration.

Comment: Do we use the fact that it is a fibration in this proof? I think I have a proof but I have not used the property of a fibration, so I wonder if it's correct.

Comment: No, in fact more generally for any map $p:P\to Y$ and any map $f:X\to Y$ the fiber over any point $x\in X$ in the pullback $f^*P$ is the same as the fiber over $f(x)$ in $p$. This is because taking the fiber is pulling back along the inclusion of the point $x$ into $X$ and the pullback of a pullback is a pullback.

Comment: Ah right I see, we use pulback pasting, nice! I had used an explicit calculation of the fiber. I run into one problem: since the map $hofib(f) \to X$ is a Hurewicz fibration, we know that its homotopy fiber is weakly homotopy equivalent to its fiber. So combined with the above argument we get that its homotopy fiber is weakly homotopy equivalent to $\Omega Y$. But I need to show it is homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Wait what definition of homotopy fiber are you using? Because the one I typically see is just take the fiber of an equivalent fibration, so if we're already a fibration the fiber is the homotopy fiber.

Comment: The definition I'm using is that the homotopy fiber of $f : X \to Y$ is the pullback of the evaluation map $ev_1 : PY \to Y$ along $f$. There's a lemma in my notes that for a Serre fibration $f : X \to Y$ we have that the fiber of $F$ is weakly homotopy equivalent to the homotopy fiber of $f$. Here I use that $ev_1$ is a Hurewicz fibration and hence a Serre fibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to expand on my comments and given a more complete answer.

So far we have that $\newcommand\hofib{\operatorname{hofib}}\hofib(f)\to X$ is a Hurewicz fibration, because it's the pullback of a Hurewicz fibration. Moreover its fiber $F$ is the same as the fiber of $PY\to Y$. This is a general fact that follows from pullback pasting.

Consider the following diagram where $x\in X$ is a point, and both squares are pullbacks.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>>> f^*P @>>> P\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
x @>>> X @>>> Y
\end{CD}
$$
In this case $F$ is the fiber of $f^*P$ over $x$. However the outer square is also a pullback, by pullback pasting, so $F$ is also the fiber of $P$ over $f(x)$.

So the fiber of $\hofib(f)\to X$ is $\Omega Y$. All we need to do now is show that the fiber of a Hurewicz fibration is weakly equivalent to its homotopy fiber, where the homotopy fiber is defined by pulling back the path space of the codomain to the domain.

Let's assume then that $f:X\to Y$ is some general Hurewicz fibration (of pointed spaces). Let $F=f^{-1}(*)$ be the point-set fiber of $f$. Let $G = \hofib(f) = f^* PY$. We want to produce a homotopy equivalence between $F$ and $G$. For $PY$ I'm going to assume that we take paths that end at $*$ to fix a convention. Concretely then as a set, $G$ is the set of pairs $(x, \alpha)$ where $x\in X$ and $\alpha : I\to Y$ satisfies $\alpha(0)=f(x)$ and $\alpha(1)=*$.

First of all, we always have a map $i:F\to G$, given by $x\mapsto (x,*)$, where $*\in PY$ denotes the constant path at the base point. To get a map $G\to F$ we need to use the fact that $f$ is a Hurewicz fibration. Consider the square
$$
\begin{CD}
G @>\pi_1>> X \\
@VG\times \{0\}VV @VVfV \\ 
G\times I @>>\operatorname{ev}> Y,
\end{CD}
$$
where the bottom map is $(x,\alpha,t)\mapsto \alpha(t)$.
The fact that this square commutes is the fact that if $(x,\alpha)\in G$, then $f(x) = \alpha(0)$.

Thus there exists a lift $H:G\times I \to X$. $H_0=\pi_1$, and $f\circ H_1 = *$, since $\alpha(1)=*$ for all $(x,\alpha)\in G$. Thus $H_1$ actually lands in the fiber, $F$. For convenience let's let $h=H_1$. Let's keep in mind for later use that $H$ is a homotopy between $\pi_1$ and $h$.

We now have $i:F\to G$ and $h:G\to F$. We just need to check that these maps are homotopy inverses of each other. Now $h\circ i$ is homotopic to $\pi_1\circ i$, but $\pi_1\circ i = 1_F$ by definition of $i$. For the other composition $i\circ h$, consider some element $(x,\alpha)\in G$. $h(x,\alpha) = x'$ for some $x'\in F$, and $H(x,\alpha,-)$ is a path from $x$ to $x'$ in $X$ lifting $\alpha$. This gives a path in $G$ from $(x', *)$ to $(x,\alpha)$ by $t\mapsto (H(x,\alpha,t), s\mapsto \alpha(t+s)$ (extend $\alpha$ so that $\alpha(t+s)=*$ when $t+s>1$). But this is a homotopy from $1_G$ to $i\circ h$:
$$
(g,t)\mapsto \left(H(g,t), s\mapsto \operatorname{ev}(g,t+s)\right),
$$
as desired.